# Ansible: facts gathering mech

Tags: ansible

quick question, i'm trying to add some aix specific facts using the BaseFactCollector. for some reason the facts do not show up in the setup output. what kind of wizardy has to be done to make this work?

i also added the new script to the following file.

```
facts/default_collectors.py:

from ansible.module_utils.facts.system.aix import AIXFactCollector

# general info, not required but probably useful for other facts
_general = [
    ...
    AIXFactCollector
]
```

test code (facts/system/aix.py)

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type


import sys
import shlex
import os
import platform
import re
import itertools
import commands
import subprocess
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json


from ansible.module_utils.facts.utils import get_file_content


from ansible.module_utils.facts.collector import BaseFactCollector


class AIXFactCollector(BaseFactCollector):
    """
    Some handy AIX facts, more or less nice to haves
    """
    name = 'aix_goodies'
    _fact_ids = set()
    _platform = 'AIX'

    def get_oslevel(self):
        oslevel = {}
        rc, out, err = self.module.run_command(["/usr/bin/oslevel", "-s"])
        data = out.split('-')
        oslevel['OS_VER'] = data[0].strip('0')
        oslevel['TL'] = data[1].strip('0')
        oslevel['SP'] = data[2].strip('0')
        oslevel['BUILD_DATE'] = data[3].strip()

        return oslevel
```

ansible command line

```
ansible all -i 'AIXBUILDHOSTNG,' -m setup -a 'gather_subset=aix_goodies' --tree /tmp/facts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oslevel parsing should use the existing oslevel output,  in `get_distribution_AIX`:   https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/distribution.py#L530

---

In general, the fact system is a mix of platform independent-ish code that does similar things for many OSes (`DistributionFactCollector`), and very platform specific things that only exist on one (`SelinuxFactCollector`).

I don't know all the loading mechanisms of facts. Probably best to start with specific use cases of commands you want run, with sample output you want as facts.   File these as enhancement issues, and take them to -devel  mailing list or IRC:  https://www.ansible.com/community  There you can get help enhancing existing fact collection classes, or creating new ones.

Comment: the oslevel stuff shown above should be seen as a simple example. i have many more aix specific facts to implement so i need to know how to do it correctly.